# Scraping the news (Python 3.6, BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape [spiegel.de/schlagzeilen](http://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen) to get all the news-stuff which is shown below the dates (today, yesterday, to days ago).

```
<div class="schlagzeilen-content schlagzeilen-overview">
```

contains what I want, I think, but there is one problem left:

```
print(data)
```

keeps out the data I need, but in addition it comes with a bunch of phrases I don't want (like names of the integrated modules/ parts of HTML/CSS and so on)

So I chose

```
for item in data:
    print(item.text)
```

This one has a very pretty output(!), but now I miss the article-URL, which is important to have. Is there anybody who can help me out? Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website = 'http://spiegel.de/schlagzeilen'
r = requests.get(website)
soup = BeautifulSoup((r.content), "lxml")

data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "schlagzeilen-content schlagzeilen-overview"})

for item in data:
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin

website = 'http://spiegel.de/schlagzeilen'
r = requests.get(website)
soup = BeautifulSoup((r.content), "lxml")

div = soup.find("div", {"class": "schlagzeilen-content schlagzeilen-overview"})

for a in div.find_all('a', title=True):
    link = urljoin(website, a.get('href'))
    print(a.text, a.find_next_sibling('span').text)
    print(link)
```

out:

```
Südafrika: Dutzende Patienten sterben nach Verlegung (Panorama, 13:09)
http://spiegel.de/panorama/gesellschaft/suedafrika-verlegung-in-privatkliniken-dutzende-patienten-gestorben-a-1132677.html
Trumps Stotterstart: Ein Präsident, so unbeliebt wie keiner zuvor (Politik, 12:59)
http://spiegel.de/politik/ausland/donald-trump-als-us-praesident-so-unbeliebt-wie-kein-vorgaenger-a-1132554.html
Kontrolle von Gefährdern: Kabinett beschließt elektronische Fußfessel (Politik, 12:33)
```

The tag you need is `a` tag and it's sibling `span` which contains `(Netzwelt, 12:23)`, so just use `find_all` and use `a` tag as an anchor.

And if you want the full path of the url, use `urljoin`

Comment: dear friend  - many many thanks for this awesome reply and the explanation. This just does not work any more. I tried to workout this for Python 3 but failed at the first time. Any idea to port over this solution to a newer time!? Look forward to hear from you - regards.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **[`CSS selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)** to find all article links:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website = 'http://spiegel.de/schlagzeilen'
r = requests.get(website)
soup = BeautifulSoup((r.content), "lxml")

# data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "schlagzeilen-content schlagzeilen-overview"})
links = soup.select('div.schlagzeilen-content a')

for item in links:
    print item.text, website + item['href']
```

Some output:

```
Bayern: Sechs Tote in Gartenlaube - keine Hinweise auf Gewaltverbrechen http://spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/panorama/justiz/tote-in-gartenlaube-keine-hinweise-auf-gewaltverbrechen-a-1132268.html
Starbucks, Tesla, GE: Trumps Einreiseverbot beunruhigt US-Konzerne http://spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/wirtschaft/soziales/donald-trump-und-das-einreiseverbot-us-konzerne-zeigen-sich-besorgt-a-1132262.html
...
```

Comment: dear Shane - many many thanks for this awesome reply and the explanation. This just does not work any more. I tried to workout this for Python 3 but failed at the first time. Any idea to port over this solution to a newer time!? Look forward to hear from you - regards.